# How do I loop and delete a certain key in a JSON python

Tags: python, json

I have the following JSON:

```
x = "test" : [{"a":"2",
           "b":"2",
           "c":"2",
           "d":"2",
           "e":"2",
           },
           {"a":"2",
           "x":"2",
           "c":"2",
           "d":"2",
           "e":"2",
           },
           {"a":"2",
           "y":"2",
           "c":"2",
           "d":"2",
           "e":"2",
           }],
```

I want to be able to loop over this JSON and find all keys 'x' and 'y' and delete them. I have no issues deleting keys that exist across all JSON objects, however, when it comes to object specific keys like 'x' and 'y' I seem to be hitting an obstacle.

What I have tried so far:

```
for i in x['test']:
     del(i['x'])
     del(i['y'])
```

But then I get this error:

```
KeyError: 'extension'
```

All help is appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The first dictionary doesn't have `x` (`'extension'`) key, you need to check if it exists first

```
for i in x['test']:
    if 'x' in i:
        del (i['x'])
    if 'y' in i:
        del (i['y'])
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use a try except block it will skip the elements for which the keys do not exist

```
for i in x['test']:
    try:
        del(i['x'])
    except:
        pass
    try:
        del(i['y'])
    except:
        pass
print(x)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  alist=x['test']
  for item in alist:
      if item.get("x"):
          item.pop("x")
      if item.get("y"):
          item.pop("y")

  print(alist)
```

Comment: It would be good if you could explain the answer, that will help the OP even more.